# Open source SIEM for SQL Server, Active Directory, WatchGuard Firewall

Tags: linux, open-source, siem

I need an open source [security information and event management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_information_and_event_management) piece of software that can manage logs from:

- SQL Server
- Active Directory
- WatchGuard Firewall